# Parallelize 20K requests + filter & concat results into 1 dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, api

I need to make around 20K API calls, each one returns a CSV file and then on that file I have to perform some operations, finally, concatenate all the results into a single dataframe.

I've completed this task sequentially, but the issue is that each API Call lasts around 1sec and it takes around 6h to complete. So, I would like parallelize the task as I can make up to 100 simulatenous API calls and up to 1000 calls per minute.

I've tried several stuff, but I'm struggling... I have accomplished to parallelize the tasks and complete 200 API calls in about 8 seconds, but I can't concat all the results into a single dataframe... Would appreciate any help.

Thanks! :)

This is what i have:

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
```

Comment: I get an error because from time.time() is not an valid start date

Comment: @bitflip if i just print df instead of returning it i got the running time without error, so i think the issue is not here. thanks anyways!

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could use [dask.dataframe](https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/dataframe.html), which gives an API much like that of pandas and handles parallelization over multiple threads, processes, or physical servers:

```
import dask
import dask.distributed
import dask.dataframe
import pandas as pd

# start a dask client
client = dask.distributed.Client()

tickers = tickers[:200]

# map your job over the tickers
futures = client.map(scrape, tickers)

# wait for the jobs to finish, then filter out the Null return values
dask.distributed.wait(futures)
non_null_futures = [f for f in futures if f.type != type(None)]

# convert the futures to a single dask.dataframe
ddf = dask.dataframe.from_delayed(non_null_futures)

# if desired, you can now convert to pandas
df = ddf.compute()

# alternatively, you could write straight to disk, giving
# a partitioned binary file, e.g.
ddf.to_parquet("myfile.parquet")
```

Comment: thank you so much! I get an error tho: (AttributeError: module 'dask' has no attribute 'wait')

Comment: oops sorry - it's `dask.distributed.wait`

Answer (score 0):

I have a few issues recreating the data:

```
start_time = time.time()  # invalid start time

df = df[df.gap > 30] # returns an empty df since all values for gap are below 30
```

Suggestion:
You can set `&fmt=json` to have an easier time creating your df

```
df = pd.DataFrame(r.json())
```

If I change those things, your code works as expected.
Please provide a list of tickers and a reproducible example. (I have an API key)

Comment: thank you, just figured out. the issue was with one of the tickers which dataframe had different column values, so just filtered for dataframes with desired columns: ```if {'Open', 'Close'}.issubset(df.columns):```

Comment: also, by using ```&fmt=json``` instead of simple csv call i get similar time results, but i find it weird tbh...